SOSL query on ContentVersion not returning consistent results for all users
I need to search for keywords in some files in Salesforce. I am using the following SOSL query for the same:
FIND {search_term} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING ContentVersion(ContentDocumentId, FileExtension, Title WHERE Id IN (comma_separated_ContentVersionIds))

According to the documentation, queries on ContentVersion do not return all files for all users unless they are explicitly shared. So we need to filter based on Ids.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm


I did the same in my query above and I am still not getting consistent results for all users. For the owner of the files, the above query is returning 3 results while for some other users, it's returning either 0 or 1.
Can anyone please help with what is going wrong? Am I missing something? Is there any work around this?

How are you getting the IDs to filter on?

@PhilW
I am getting the LatestPublishedVersionId from Content DocumentLink using the below query:
SELECT LinkedEntityId, ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId IN:kavArtMap.keySet()
Even when I hardcode the Ids (for testing), it doesn't give consistent results.

This is the solution that worked for me:
Even after sharing the files, the SOSL query was not returning all the search results if the search keyword was in the versionData unless I was the file owner. If the keyword was in the Title, I was getting results.
I used REST callout to get results for the matching keyword in the VersionData for all users regardless of ownership.
Set the endpoint as the current org's URL and then query the records

String endPoint =
'callout:named_credential/services/data/v58.0/search?q='+(encodedQuery.replace('
','+'));

Please note: you will have to pass the IDs of the ContentVersions or the ContentDocument IDs in the query to get the results.
